# go dependency typerror when building locally with `go get`

Tags: go, aws-sdk

Here's a simplified version of my file structure

```
├── honeyelb
|   └── main.go
├── state
|   └── state.go
└── vendor
    └── ...
```

Both `honeyelb/main.go` and `state/main.go` are importing the same `aws-sdk-go` dependency as follows:

```
import (
    ...
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
)
```

Additionally, `honeyelb/main.go` imports `state/state.go` as a dependency as follows:

```
import (
  ...
  "github.com/honeycombio/honeyaws/state"
)
```

When I use `go get github.com/honeycombio/honeyaws/cmd/honeyelb` the tool installs fine, and there's no complaints about dependencies.

The problem is when I try to `go build honeyelb/main.go` locally; I can see that `honeyelb/main.go` and `state/state.go` are pulling the `aws/session` dependency from different locations:

> cmd/honeyelb2/main.go:99:41: cannot use sess (type
>   *"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session".Session) as type *"github.com/honeycombio/honeyaws/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session".Session
>   in argument to state.NewDynamoDBStater

How do I get them to both build from the dependencies in `vendor/`?

Comment: If an import vendors dependencies, you also need to correctly vendor your dependencies.

Comment: @JimB apologies but I'm a Go newbie...how would I go about doing that? I tried adding `state/` to my `vendor/` folder but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: One normally uses dependency management tools like `dep`, `govendor`, `glide`, etc (the selection and use of which is off topic). If this is just for local experimentation, everything _might_ run off the current versions if you remove the `vendor/` folder entirely.

Comment: @JimB hmmm removing `vendor/` didn't quite do it

Comment: ended up following this guide to setting up a go dev environment: https://skife.org/golang/2013/03/24/go_dev_env.html, which is doing the trick!